# How to return the correct heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview, ios8

Right now I'm trying to adapt for the two new iPhone 6 / Plus. I'm using UITableViewController to implement my Table.

Inside my Cell I have an UImageView of 320x189 using pretty much the whole cell and acting as the background of each cell.

The image that I'm getting its dynamic and sizes will vary, so I can't control the size of the image. With the use of the constraints I'm able to adapt the the image trough whole cells. But I feel that with the iPhone 6 Plus the height of the cell should be at least 20px more in height.

Is there any way that I can detect the its an iPhone 6 Plus/ 6 and on the heightForRowAtIndexPath method override the height returned ? O maybe should I use a different StoryBoard for the iPhone 6/ Plus?

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect what phone it is based on the screen height. These are the screen dimensions for the iPhone 4 and 5: http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html, and these are the dims for the iPhone 6/6+: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified.

The iPhone 4 has a height of 480 pts, the iPhone 5 a height of 568 pts, iPhone 6 a height of 667 pts, and 6+ a height of 736 pts.

You can get the height of the device's screen with `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height`.

So you can tell what kind of phone you're using:

```
CGFloat h = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
if (h > 700){
    NSLog(@"iPhone 6+");
}
else if (h > 600){
    NSLog(@"iPhone 6");
}
else if (h > 500){
    NSLog(@"iPhone 5");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"iPhone 4");
}
```

---

As for the height of the table cell, you could programmatically set the height to whatever the size of the image is in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method. If you have your images in some sort of array, you could do:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return images[indexPath.row].size.height;
}
```

Which should adjust the height of each cell to fit its corresponding image.

Hope this helps!